# What view is used in play store Review VIew

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to create a view like Play store Reviews View, I am not getting which view to use,

I tried using progress bar but it didn't work out for me, Can anyone suggest me with which view I can make out that. Or I need to use OpenGraph (Bar Graph) for that

[image: Please Refer below Pic]

Comment: I think that is web app, not native...

Comment: Means I can't do it on android client app?

Comment: No no... You can do, you need to write your custom views for that.. but wait if any one knows any better API or solution...

Answer (score 1):

The Playstore app is using a custom view called `HistogramTable`, which has `TableRow`s containing another custom view called `HistogramBar`. Pull up the `HierarchyViewer` and you can see for yourself:
[image: Playstore rating bar exposed!]

I'm guessing the HistogramBar accepts a `max` and `currentVal` and applies a fill color onto it's on width depending on `currentVal/max`.